# Building OpenWrt with ImageBuilder offline

Tags: openwrt

I'm having a Carambola2 developer Board and building a firmware with the ImageBuilder from OpenWrt. This works great. But I would like to build the firmware when I'm offline. Because by default it tries to download data from 8devices.com. When I'm offline it compiles well but it's slow because it tries to access the internet. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is the following:

Step 1: Remove the rm-command for DL_DIR in the clean target of the Makefile.

Step 2: Add pkg.8devices.com to hosts.deny file.

So you will need an internet connection only the first time and every time you want to add a new package.

I think it's not a clean solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Image builder will need internet, or otherwise you download all packages which you need and save it to "**dl**" folder or you can build it offline you can try building openwrt using source code. You can check this [link](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=Tutorial_of_compiling_OpenWRT)
 for building image using source code.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't like to build via source code. The folder for that is very big.